# How do I get two JavaScript references to the same HTML-form to work?

Tags: javascript

I'm having trouble validating an HTML form with JavaScript. On their own they each work, but together they don't.

**This works:**

```
// Make sure the e-mail address is valid
function validateEmail(mailform,email) { 
    var reg = /^([A-Za-z0-9_\-\.])+\@([A-Za-z0-9_\-\.])+\.([A-Za-z]{2,4})$/;
    var address = document.forms[mailform].elements[email].value;
    if(reg.test(address) == false) {
        alert('E-mail not valid');
        return false;
    } 
}
```

Attribute in the form:

```
onsubmit="javascript:return validateEmail('mailform', 'email');"
```

**And this works:**

```
// Make sure the message is long enough
function validateBody(mailform,mailbody) { 
    var msg = document.forms[mailform].elements[mailbody].value.length;
    if (msg < 3) {
        alert('Too hort');
        return false;
    }
}
```

Attribute in the form:

```
onsubmit="javascript:return validateBody('mailform', 'mailbody');"
```

**But this doesn't work:**

```
// Make sure the e-mail address is valid AND that the message is long enough
function validateForm(mailform,email,mailbody) { 
    var reg = /^([A-Za-z0-9_\-\.])+\@([A-Za-z0-9_\-\.])+\.([A-Za-z]{2,4})$/;
    var address = document.forms[mailform].elements[email].value;
    var msg = document.forms[mailform].elements[mailbody].value.length;
    if(reg.test(address) == false) {
        alert('Please enter a valid e-mail address');
        return false;
    } else if (msg < 3) {
        alert('Text too hort');
        return false;
    }
}
```

Attribute in the form:

```
onsubmit="javascript:return validateForm('mailform', 'email', 'mailbody');"
```

**Why?**

As I said, they work each on their own, but even as different functions, they don't work together.

Comment: Where does `mailform` come from in your second example? And you never use the parameter `email`...

Comment: How do they not work: They don't catch errors or they don't submit correct input? Do you get any javascript errors?

Comment: I don't get any errors. It doesn't react to "correct" input. (Yeah, I'm new to JavaScript.)

Yes, I do use 'email'...
'mailform' comes from <form id="mailform" name="contactform" method="post" action="send_form_email.php" onsubmit="javascript:return validate('mailform', 'email');">

Comment: How is it supposed to react on "correct" input? It looks like it should just pass and return undefined.

Comment: Undefined in what way? Why do they work each on their own, then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have two functions which work, why not use those?

```
function validateForm(mailform,email,mailbody) { 
var addressValid = validateEmail(mailform,email);
var bodyValid = validateBody(mailform,mailbody);
return addressValid && bodyValid
}
```

The `return` will only return `true` if both tests are `true`. The advantage of this method is (as well as being likely to work) that it's easily extended and easily maintained.

If you only want one alert if there are two errors, then you'll need to test `addressValid` and call `bodyValid` only if required.

Answer (score 1):

Use `if (msg < 3)` instead of `else if (msg < 3)` .

Comment: @Kebman Did you try to add `return true;` line before the end of `validateForm` function's body?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use `javascript:` in the `onsubmit` attribute, remove that part.

Also, you would benefit greatly from using a JavaScript library such as [jQuery](https://jquery.com/).

Comment: Thank you! Removed. Otherwise I want to learn this the hard way before I do it the easy way. :)